# Django - Annotate Count() of distinct values grouped by Date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have the following Model:

```
class Visualization(models.Model):
    ....
    user: FK user
    start_time: DATETIME
    product: FK product
    ....
```

Example data:

| User ID | Start Time | Product ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-07 14:03:07 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-09-07 13:06:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-09-07 17:03:06 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-09-07 04:03:05 | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-09-07 15:03:17 | 4 |
| 1 | 2021-09-07 19:03:27 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-06 21:03:31 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-09-06 11:03:56 | 9 |
| 1 | 2021-09-06 07:03:19 | 9 |

I need to get the active users for days, the active users are those who made at least one reproduction, if a user made many reproductions, it still counts as 1.

A correct answer would be:

| Total | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-09-07 |
| 2 | 2021-09-06 |

First I make an annotation a Truncate of StartTime to keep only the Date and then I make Group By for this annotation, so far everything without problems. The problem is when I try to count the Users since they have repetitions. I have tried to count the User_id with Distinct = True, but the numbers still give me bad, also by a very big difference.
I also tried grouping by user_id and period (annotation of Truncate StartTime) but it didn't work for me either.

Real Data Example from 1 Day

```
| User ID | Start Time | Product ID |
| :----: | :----------: | :-------: |
|5852|2021-09-07 11:33:48.000000 +00:00|0|
|5852|2021-09-07 11:33:38.000000 +00:00|2|
|6697|2021-09-07 11:31:55.000000 +00:00|3|
|6697|2021-09-07 11:31:31.000000 +00:00|1|
|6643|2021-09-07 11:28:29.000000 +00:00|1598|
|2703|2021-09-07 11:19:05.000000 +00:00|1620|
|6697|2021-09-07 11:18:40.000000 +00:00|3|
|6697|2021-09-07 11:17:32.000000 +00:00|1|
|28295|2021-09-07 11:11:34.000000 +00:00|1618|
|6697|2021-09-07 11:11:33.000000 +00:00|3|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:54:25.000000 +00:00|0|
|6697|2021-09-07 10:53:05.000000 +00:00|1|
|6697|2021-09-07 10:52:53.000000 +00:00|3|
|6697|2021-09-07 10:50:44.000000 +00:00|1|
|11|2021-09-07 10:48:06.000000 +00:00|1478|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:47:53.000000 +00:00|0|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:45:22.000000 +00:00|0|
|28283|2021-09-07 10:20:18.000000 +00:00|1191|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:19:58.000000 +00:00|2|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:19:37.000000 +00:00|0|
|23968|2021-09-07 10:19:20.000000 +00:00|2|
|11|2021-09-07 09:09:22.000000 +00:00|1436|
|359|2021-09-07 09:08:59.000000 +00:00|88|
|359|2021-09-07 09:07:32.000000 +00:00|100|
|28275|2021-09-07 08:59:39.000000 +00:00|2|
|28275|2021-09-07 08:50:31.000000 +00:00|2|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:46:10.000000 +00:00|1572|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:45:42.000000 +00:00|2|
|359|2021-09-07 08:41:48.000000 +00:00|1550|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:26:42.000000 +00:00|0|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:19:21.000000 +00:00|2|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:18:14.000000 +00:00|0|
|23968|2021-09-07 08:16:33.000000 +00:00|0|
|2703|2021-09-07 07:01:28.000000 +00:00|1620|
|2703|2021-09-07 06:59:43.000000 +00:00|1620|
|6697|2021-09-07 02:51:50.000000 +00:00|0|
|6697|2021-09-07 02:46:18.000000 +00:00|2|
|10452|2021-09-07 00:15:03.000000 +00:00|421|
|27953|2021-09-07 00:12:35.000000 +00:00|1|
```

returns 20 instead of 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a query like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Visualization.objects.values(
    date=TruncDate('start_time')
).annotate(
    total=Count('user', distinct=True)
).order_by('date')
```

For days where no reproduction is made, there will *not* be row in the `QuerySet`, so you will need to post-process these dates.

Comment: Try to do it like this and it still returns the total wrong, it returns many more than there really are.

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: what version of Django are you using?

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: If I use your sample data, I get `<QuerySet [{'date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 6), 'total': 2}, {'date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 7), 'total': 3}]>` as result, which seems to be the expected result.

Comment: I am trying to add a real data set, but I have not been able to.

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: but exactly what result do you get right now (for the given sample data)?

Comment: I just edited the post with a larger example without table formatting because it gives me an error.
I use Django 3.2

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: what is the outcome of `print(qs.query)` with `qs` as the queryset.

Comment: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', "startTime" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "period", COUNT(DISTINCT "user_id") AS "total" FROM WHERE ("startTime" >= 2021-09-04 02:00:00+02:00 AND "startTime" <= 2021-09-07 19:06:52.073740+02:00) GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "startTime" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') ORDER BY "period" ASC

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: isn't it possible that due to the Madrid timezone, the dates truncate at a different time, so since all your dates are +00:00, but now you split these by +02:00. This thus means that everything around 22:00 is passed as the next day, so the "splitting" is done differently.

Comment: @YoelAcevedo: what if you use `import pytz` and `TruncDate('start_time', tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **extra() QuerySet modifier** for group by date query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Visualization.objects.extra(
    select={'start_date': 'date( start_time )'}
).values(
    'start_date'
).annotate(
    total=Count('user', distinct=True)
)
```